# Symfony 2 not finding primary key of mapped entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am having an issue with the primary key of a mapped entity not being detected by doctrine.

I have 2 tables, users and operators.  There is a unidirectional many to one relationship between users and operators.

User entity is defined as

```
XXX\SecurityBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    repositoryClass: XXX\SecurityBundle\Repository\UserRepository
    table: XXX_USER
    id:
        id: 
            type: integer
            unsigned: false
            nullable: false
            column: ID
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        username:
            type: string
            length: 32
            nullable: false
            column: USERNAME
...
    manyToOne:
        operator:
            targetEntity: XXX\CoreDataBundle\Entity\Operator
            joinColumn:
            name: operator_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

The operators entity defined as

```
XXX\CoreDataBundle\Entity\Operator:
    type: entity
    respositoryClass: XXX\CoreDataBundle\Repository\OperatorRepository
    table: OPERATORS
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            unsigned: false
            nullable: false
            column: ID
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        operName:
            type: string
            length: 32
            nullable: false
            column: OPERATOR_NAME
```

When validating the schema,  I receive the following error :

- The referenced column name 'id' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class 'XXX\CoreDataBundle\Entity\Operator'.

When I try to assign an operator to a user, I receive the following error :

[ErrorException]
  Notice: Undefined index: id in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line
  607

As far as I can see,  'id' is set as the primary key of the operator entity.  The database behind doctrine is oracle, in is in sync with the entity definitions and the primary key is set correctly on the database.

Anyone able to spot my error in defining the mapping ?

I do not think the fact the entities are in different bundles is an issue as I am getting similar issues with entities in the same bundle.

Thank you.

Comment: In many-to-one relationships, `referencedColumnName` cannot be other than primary_keys, there exist no documentation about it as far as i know. I had the same issue, and keep on using only primary keys in reference column names.

Comment: In this case (as I understand it) the referencedColumnName is the primary key of the operator entity and it is not finding it.

Comment: I guess i figured out your question wrongly. But i have another idea, oracle is case sensitive and i am not sure about what doctrine does with the column names, but can you try to set your column Name `id` instead of `ID`in both entity? just an idea since doctrine generates referenced column names as default and ID and id may be differing, it sounds silly i know but just an idea as i say...

Comment: Thank you,  it is case sensitivity that is causing the problem.  Oracle is not case sensitive (but by convention uses uppercase) but the matching of the referenced column name is case sensitive.  If I change the referenced column name to 'ID' it validates.

Comment: Happy for you, one arrow up ;)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's columns and table names are always uppercase. So if using them, you need to put the referencedColumnName in uppercase even if in the PHP side it is lowercase.